# Can reverse proxy in Service Fabric be used with multiple windows containers?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm evaluating using SF or docker swarm for container orchestration and I can see service fabric has an edge by being able to use reverse proxy implementation which runs on all nodes in cluster. Problem is that I can see that based on cluster manifest only one port can be used as reverse proxy port and hence I'm not fully understanding how this can be utilized if you have multiple windows containers running with each of those running on their own port. I need to use port:port mapping only (with no HTTP rewrite), so ultimately wanted one to one reverse port mapping to each individual windows container running. 
Is it possible to accomplish by using service fabric?

To be clear I have www.app1.com and www.app2.com hosted in 2 different containers, they don't need to talk to each other. I deploy those to service fabric, how do I use reverse proxy with single published external port to reach those containers externally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time (version 5.6 of Service Fabric), Reverse Proxy will do the service resolution using the Service Fabric naming service and provide the URI to get to your service. The URL that reverse proxy will find your service on is specific to Service Fabric - e.g. http://clusterFQDN/appName/serviceName:port.

What you can use the DNS Service to get you a container IP (the IP of a host node in the cluster, running your container). However, you can only find the port by doing a DNS SRV record lookup.

Current best options for exposing containers in a Service Fabric cluster are:

1. If you have a fixed host port for your container, the Azure load balancer will be able to monitor where the container lives, and forward requests to only those nodes. You can add additional public IPs to your Load Balancer and use one per container. Cannot be used with dynamic host ports in the cluster.
2. Azure API Management can resolve Service Fabric services by integrating with the Service Fabric Naming Service.
3. Create your own HTTP Gateway as a Reliable Service: https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting or https://github.com/c3-ls/ServiceFabric-Http
4. Running Nginx as a service in the cluster: Based on this prototype you can run and configure Nginx in Service Fabric: https://github.com/knom/ServiceFabric-Nginx

Comment: Sad but this makes Service Fabric is not a contender in windows containers with limitation of single published port. Swarm load balancer (routing mesh( does not have this limitation (when it comes to Windows). Every service will have their own published port

Comment: It's a single port per VM host in the cluster, not the whole cluster. The individual containers can use the same ports. That is no different than in a swarm cluster. You can compare the swarm mesh mode routing with what nginx or you own HTTP gateway will do in a Service Fabric cluster.

Comment: swarm mesh will allocate a port for each of services deployed to cluster, while ServiceFabric allocates single port for all of them. So if I have 2 completely isolated containers hosting one www.app1.com and another one www.app2.com then I publish 2 services on different ports in swarm and any request to one of those ports on any node in swarm will end up routing to correct containers. This is impossible to do with service fabric alone,correct?

Comment: "while ServiceFabric allocates single port for all of them" - You decide, either you set the port or use a dynamically assigned port.

Comment: Port hosted on individual nodes shall be static since external load balancer will route traffic to it, so dynamic ports are out of the question. External LB will have two VIPs sending traffic for www.app1.com to one port on all nodes and for www.app2.com to another port on all hosts. Routing mesh will route traffic to underlying containers. Service Fabric can not do that, right?

Comment: All of the above would help you achieve that. Number one is the one that comes closest to what you are describing.

Comment: This is for standalone SF implementation and LB is not SF aware. So SF can not do what routing mesh from SWARM can do on it's own for multicontainer application setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Reverse proxy with multiple containers. The idea is simple

- Configure port to host mapping so your host knows which port your
  application is listening
- Configure container to container so your
  container register a end point with service fabric. You can choose
  the port for this endpoint. This will be registered with Naming
  service and available for reverse proxy
- Communication between containers can be done using reverse proxy using the service name and the port you specified. if you didn't specified the port number then service fabric will assign one for you and you can get it using environment variable.

Service Fabric team have excellent documentation about this here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-container-linux

Comment: There is only one entry available for reverse proxy port in cluster configuration. I need cluster to handle more then single type of container via different reverse proxy port on host. Is it possible? Containers don't need to talk to each other

Comment: If the second step can specify multiple end point each end point then will have a port, These end points then will be registered to Naming service. That way you can have a host with multiple end point each with different port.#

Comment: To be clear I have www.app1.com and www.app2.com hosted in 2 different containers, they don't need to talk to each other. I deploy those to app fabric, how do I use reverse proxy with single published external port to reach those containers?

Comment: uhmm can you have unique endpoint with naming service ? If you cant then you need post sharing

Comment: This is container, it does not know anything outside of it. All it does is listening on port 80 and respond. Not sure what unique port mapping is. Just need to be able to go to reverse proxy port of cluster, get www.app1.com and supposed to get response from one of containers running inside service fabric, the same with www.app2.com